# Matlab finding if graphic object exist on figure on given coordinates

Tags: matlab

I need to find a way to check if a patch object I created (a rectangle for example) exists within certain X-Y coordinates I specify. As an example, I am using the following code:

```
a = figure
b = axes('Parent',a,'Xlim',[0 100],'Ylim',[0 100])
x = [0 10 10 0];
y = [0 0 10 10];
patch(x,y,'red')
```

Now I would like to know if there is an object in the figure in the point with coordinates x=6 and y=3. Is there a way to check this?

Comment: I dont know any direct way, but you could try: findall(a,'Children') and then checking if the position is in a given range

Comment: For a single polygon (i.e. if you have the y and y coordinate of the vertices) it is a oneliner: ``inpolygon(6, 3, x, y)`` returns ``true``, whereas ``inpolygon(6, 30, x, y)`` returns ``false``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the findall () and inpolygon function.

```
 hPatches = findall(b, 'type', 'patch');
 tgtX = 5; tgtY = 7;
 inside = zeros (1, numel(hPatches));
 for patchCtr = 1:numel(hPatches)
     vert = get (hPatches(patchCtr), 'Vertices');
     inside(patchCtr) = inpolygon (tgtX, tgtY, vert(:,1), vert(:,2));
 end
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use findobj to find the objects of interest, in this case patch objects, and access their 'XData' property, then check if it falls within some range. You can do the same with the YData property as well.

Here is an example:

```
clc
clear
close all

a=figure;
b=axes('Parent',a,'Xlim',[0 30],'Ylim',[0 30]);

x1 = [0 10 10 0];
y1 = [0 0 10 10];

x2 = [15 25 25 15];
y2= [10 10 20 20];

patch(x1,y1,'red')
patch(x2,y2,'blue')

hPatches = findall(a,'Type','patch') %// find patch objects

InfoPatches = get(hPatches); %// Get info about the objects. Check for the XData property.

XDataArray = zeros(4,numel(InfoPatches));
for k = 1:numel(InfoPatches)


    XDataArray(:,k) = InfoPatches(k).XData; %// Access the XData property, or any you want.

end

XDataArray
```

Figure:

[image]

And XDataArray look like this:

XDataArray =

```
15     0
25    10
25    10
15     0
```

Now there would be the part in which you check whether an object is at some position but that's quite easy to implement. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you are familiar with toolboxes, but the [mpt-toolbox](http://control.ee.ethz.ch/~mpt/3/) could come in handy here (from my Uni).

After you have installed it, you could define the rectangle as a polytope and simply check if a point is within the rectangle.
For your code example above:

```
Vertices = [0,0;10,0;10,10;0,10];
Rectangle = Polyhedron(Vertices);
TestPoint = [6;3];
Within = Rectangle.contains(Testpoint);
```

Were `Within` is a boolean variable (1 if point within `Rectangle`, 0 otherwise)

**EDIT**

Of course, the toolbox also works for intersections between your original `Rectangle` polygon and say another polygon `Intersect`.

Comment: Great toolbox, but sadly i need to do it with basic toolboxes... Still thank you!

Comment: no problem! Indeed, the toolbox is useful for linear programming and the like :)