# Determine if patch is in bounds of another patch

Tags: matlab

This is continuation of my last question: [Matlab finding if graphic object exist on figure on given coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26586946/matlab-finding-if-graphic-object-exist-on-figure-on-given-coordinates/)

I am trying to determine if one patch object is in bounds of another patch object. In my last question i got answer about inpoly method. Sadly, inpoly won't work if no polygons are in range.

Example:

```
%creating figure
a = figure
b = axes('Parent',a,'Xlim',[0 100],'Ylim',[0 100])
%first object
x = [50 60 40 50]
y = [10 40 40 10]
c = patch(x,y,'blue')
%second object
x2 = [40 50 50 40]
y2 = [20 20 30 30]
d = patch(x2,y2,'red')
%third object
x3 = [45 55 55 45]
y3 = [12 12 16 16]
e = patch(x3,y3,'yellow')
```

Now if i use inpoly to check if objects d and e are in boundaries of object c i will get positive results for d, cause atleast two of its polygons are inside of b object.

> in = inpolygon(x2,y2,x,y)
>
> in =
>
> ```
>  0     1     1     0
> ```

But i will get false result for e patch. Which is result expected for this method.

> > > in = inpolygon(x,y,x3,y3)
>
> in =
>
> ```
>  0     0     0     0
> ```

Is there a way to check for collision of those two patch objects without need of using inpoly?